# Conversion between NSString and uint8_t [] array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, arrays, nsstring

i've an NSString like this:

```
NSString *myStr=@"7JXAX";
```

that is equal in ASCII decimal value to {7,74,88,65,88}.

So, what i want to do is to convert this NSString to an uint8_t array value like:

```
uint8_t someInt[myStr length]={7,74,88,65,88};
```

So the question is, in which way can i convert a string to a unit8_t array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 55 is 7 in Hex value, 7 is 7 in decimal value.

Comment: So you want to convert the _letters_ to ASCII codes, but convert the _numbers_ to the decimal equivalent? That's a slightly more complicated procedure. If that is what you want, then follow Toby's answer, then use a for loop, which subtracts '0' for every element in the array which is >= '0' and <= '9'.

Comment: You right, i'm working with a microcontroller and if i send decimal values or hex values is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will `[myStr UTF8String]` do the job for you?

i.e:

```
uint8_t *someInt = (uint8_t *)[myStr UTF8String];
```

Comment: I think this return a pointer to uint8_t?, i need that returns an array of uint8_t, then i can acces someInt[index].

Comment: That's just what Toby's code does. You can use someInt[index] after running his example code.